# Making new repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, git-bash, git-branch

I've been self learning and while making repository in GitHub, I noticed that I have an extra line displayed in contrast to the tutorials I am watching despite doing exactly what the tutorial does.

This is what the tutorials is displaying:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov1oU.jpg)

This is mine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FFbs.jpg)

I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
What does this do?
Should I just not include that line when I'm copying it in the terminal?

I know that it's supposed to connect the local and remote repository together. Im just bothered that thee is a different line that displaying on mine despite doing the tutorials as it is. Is it just because I am using the updated version of GitHub whereas the tutorial was done in the past and (maybe) using an older version, hence the difference?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same topic than through me off a while ago:

some git tools and versions differ in using "master" or "main" as the name for your branch that is basically the base (the main/master branch) of your repository.

maybe that's what is the additional line in your screenshot, the UI thinking it is "not the normal" master/main branch it expects.

my main branches are now all called "main" but there was a time (don't now of the video) when it was master.....but than all this master/slave stuff happended.....

> Previously, the name of the default branch of any repository was “master”. But from October-2020 onward, the default branch of any GitHub repository is using “main” as the default branch name, instead of master. [from https://madhaviuyanahewa.medium.com/ever-wonder-what-the-difference-between-the-main-branch-and-the-master-branch-of-git-cb9a2bbab8bf#:~:text=Previously%2C%20the%20name%20of%20the,branch%20name%2C%20instead%20of%20master.]